# Why don't you want to put mint in a compost pile?

Tags: compost

A video by UC Berkeley on YouTube said that [you don't want to put mint in compost](https://youtu.be/kvy5sSdHPIM?t=35m48s). Why not? He also said no Bermuda grass, but I know why this is the case, essentially due to one of their other videos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mint can be propagated using stem cuttings so you'll probably end up having the mint invade your compost pile. And you may not be able to easily eradicate it after that.

Comment: ... then from the compost pile to anywhere else you try to use the compost.

Comment: Which is why there are two rules on Mint, 1) DO NOT PUT ANY MINT IN A PILE AFTER IT REACHES SEED STAGE, and 2) TURN YOUR PILE AND MAKE SURE EVERYTHING IS THOROUGHLY COMPOSTED UNTO DEATH. If only I could eradicate it from where it was originally planted, the garden where I use the compost doesn't have an issue.